# Finding the total number of records per customer in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that links my customers to DVDs they have checked out. My table is called CustomerDvds. That table looks like this:

```
CustomerDvds
- ID
- CustomerID
- DvdID
- CheckOutDate
- CheckInDate
```

I am trying to write a query that will tell me how many DVDs each customer has checked out on a specific date. Currently, I have written the following:

```
SELECT
  CustomerID,
  SUM(DvdID) as 'DVDCount'
FROM
  CustomerDvds
WHERE
  [CheckOutDate]<=GetUtcDate() AND
  [CheckInDate]>GetUtcDate()
GROUP BY
  [CustomerID]
```

Unfortunately, my DVDCount value seems way high. What am I doing wrong? How do I fix this query?

Thanks

Comment: You may want to snag the current date before the query and use it throughout: `declare @Today as Date = GetUtcDate()`  It's more of a problem when using `DateTime` and chasing a moving target as the query executes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you want COUNT not SUM...

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`COUNT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175997.aspx) aggregate not [`SUM`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187810.aspx).

You are adding up the value of the ids for each customer (which is not going to give you anything useful) rather than counting how many there are.